# EF Core Update Previous Object Id Value When i am Trying to Add new Object in One to One relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one, ef-core-3.1

I use the code-first approach, I have 2 tables in a one-to-one relationship.
I am trying to add 2 records in tables MaterialRelease and OrderMaterialRelease
the records add successfully in Table MaterialRelease, But in Table OrderMaterialRelease the first record add and then the second record update the first record id

```
 public partial class MaterialRelease
{

    public int MaterialReleaseId { get; set; }


    public int MaterialCategoryId { get; set; }

    public int MaterialId { get; set; }

    public int? MaterialTypeId { get; set; }

    public int? MaterialReleaseSizeId { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public int ReasonId { get; set; }

    public int? ByOrderOfLeaderId { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public int SortNo { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime AdditionTime { get; set; }


    public virtual OrderMaterialRelease OrderMaterialRelease { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }

    public virtual MaterialCategory MaterialCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual MaterialReleaseReasons MaterialReleaseReasons { get; set; }

    public virtual MaterialSize MaterialReleaseSize { get; set; }

    public virtual MaterialType MaterialType { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedUser { get; set; }

    public virtual User ByOrderOfLeader { get; set; }
}

    public partial class OrderMaterialRelease
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int MaterialReleaseId { get; set; }  

    public int? ProductId { get; set; }

    public int? ProductCombinedId { get; set; }

    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal WastQuantity { get; set; }

    public int SortNo { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime AdditionTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    public MaterialRelease MaterialRelease { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductCombined ProductCombined { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The function that adds to the database

```
        private void MaterialReleaseProduct(Order order)
    {
        foreach (var orderProduct in order.OrderProduct)
        {
            if (orderProduct.Product.Material != null)
            {
                var noSSizeInBSize =
                    GlobalData.unitOfWork.MaterialSizeConversion
                        .SingleOrDefault(e =>
                            e.SmallSizeId == orderProduct.Product.MaterialSizeId
                            && e.BigSizeId == orderProduct.Product.ReleaseSizeId)
                        .NoSSizeInBSize;

                var originalQuantity = orderProduct.Quantity / noSSizeInBSize;
                var wastQuantity = originalQuantity * (orderProduct.Product.MaterialWastRatio ?? 0) / 100;
                var quantity = (int) Math.Ceiling(originalQuantity + wastQuantity);
                var materialRelease = new MaterialRelease
                {
                    MaterialCategory = orderProduct.Product.MaterialCategory,
                    Material = orderProduct.Product.Material,
                    MaterialReleaseSize = orderProduct.Product.ReleaseSize,
                    MaterialType = orderProduct.Product.MaterialType,
                    Quantity = quantity,
                    Department = orderProduct.Product.Department,
                    ReasonId = 1,
                    CreatedUser = GlobalData.LoginUser,
                };


                var orderMaterialRelease = new OrderMaterialRelease
                {
                    Order = order,
                    MaterialRelease = materialRelease,
                    Product = orderProduct.Product,
                    Quantity = originalQuantity,
                    WastQuantity = wastQuantity,
                    User = GlobalData.LoginUser
                };

                GlobalData.unitOfWork.OrderMaterialReleases.Add(orderMaterialRelease);
                GlobalData.unitOfWork.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
 public int Complete()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Configuration

```
 public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OrderMaterialRelease> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.MaterialReleaseId);

        builder.HasIndex(e => new
        {
            e.OrderId,
            e.ProductId,
            e.ProductCombinedId,
        }).IsUnique();

        builder.Property(e => e.AdditionTime).HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");
        builder.Property(e => e.IsEnabled).HasDefaultValueSql("1");
        builder.Property(e => e.IsDeleted).HasDefaultValueSql("0");

        builder.HasOne(e => e.MaterialRelease)
            .WithOne(e => e.OrderMaterialRelease)
            .HasForeignKey<OrderMaterialRelease>(e => e.MaterialReleaseId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne(e => e.Product)
            .WithMany(e => e.OrderMaterialRelease)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


        builder.HasOne(e => e.ProductCombined)
            .WithMany(e => e.OrderMaterialRelease)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductCombinedId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
```

The Records in Database
MaterialRelease Table

```
MaterialReleaseId   MaterialCategoryId  MaterialId  MaterialTypeId  MaterialReleaseSizeId   Quantity    Notes   ReasonId    ByOrderOfLeaderId   DepartmentId    SortNo  IsEnabled   IsDeleted   CreatedUserId   AdditionTime
91  1   1   2   2   2   NULL    1   NULL    1   0   1   0   2   2021-05-06 09:33:36.4670000
92  1   1   3   2   2   NULL    1   NULL    1   0   1   0   2   2021-05-06 09:33:36.5100000
```

OrderMaterialRelease

```
OrderId ProductId   Quantity    WastQuantity    SortNo  IsEnabled   IsDeleted   CreatedUserId   AdditionTime    MaterialReleaseId   ProductCombinedId
61  4   1.00    0.02    0   1   0   2   2021-05-06 09:33:36.5330000 92  NULL
```

Comment: What is the PK of the `OrderMaterialRelease`? And how is the one-to-one relationship with `MaterialRelease` set-up (which of the two is the principal)? Showing relevant parts of the fluent configuration of the two entities will help identifying the issue, which sounds and most likely is caused by misconfiguration.

Comment: I modified the details and added configurations.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it looks ok (at least I don't see anything wrong in o2o configuration). Eventually the unique index, but looks like the code is setting different (order, product) pairs :-/

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev for your help. Can you suggest any solution I can try?

Comment: I have to reproduce it first in a clean environment in order to see what could be causing it.

Comment: I traced the problem with the SQL server profiler and I found that the delete query was run
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM [OrderMaterialRelease]
WHERE [MaterialReleaseId] = @p0;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

',N'@p0 int',@p0=102

I do not know why this query run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232060/discussion-between-mohamed-saqr-and-ivan-stoev).

Comment: Assuming  `unitOfWork.OrderMaterialReleases.Add(orderMaterialRelease);` is `DbSet<T>.Add`, tried reproducing with adding 2 pairs similar to the code in the post, and it does not reproduce. So there must be some code not shown here which does that. For instance,  custom override of `SaveChanges` which does something with the change tracker. Or code is not really using `DbSet<T>.Add`  but something else. It just doesn't reproduce in a clean environment, hence there is nothing I can do to help. Debug/analyze your code and find whiat is causing that deletion.

Comment: Thanks, @IvanStoev, I merged 2 tables in one table and that solves my problem for now.